# Qore dual class implementation (C++/Qore) and calling virtual method from C++ core

Tags: qore

I need implement a class *QoreFoo* in C++ and its dual implementation for Qore script *Foo* via .qpp. QoreFoo is abstract class providing general API and real functionality is to be added in descendand class (in C++ or Qore). The Foo API calls from core, i.e.C++, need to be propagated to instantiated objects regardless where descendant class is used.

*QoreFoo.h*

```
# implement general API

class QoreFoo {
public:
  virtual void bar(ExceptionSink *xsink)=0; 
};

extern QoreFoo* current_foo;

// just assign instance of a descendant of QoreFoo 
void QoreAssignFoo(QoreFoo* n_foo) {
  current_foo = n_foo;
}
```

*QoreFoo.cpp*

```
QoreFoo* current_foo = 0;
```

*any.cpp*

```
if (current_foo)
  current_foo.bar(xsink);  // propagate call via overriden method
```

When I need implement C++ descendant that is trivial:

*QoreFoo2.h*

```
class QoreFoo2: QoreFoo {
  void bar(ExceptionSink *xsink) {
    # my stuff
    printf("Hello World from C++");
  }
};
```

*usage.cpp*

```
QoreAssignFoo(new QoreFoo2);
# wait for "Hello World from C++" when core calls current_foo.bar()
.....
```

**But how to do it to propagate call to Qore script class?** I think an extra class is needed to call dual class defined in .qpp and overriden in .q

*QoreFooHelper.h*

```
class QoreFooHelper: class QoreFoo {
private:
  QoreObject* qo;
public:
  QoreFooHelper(QoreObject* n_qo): qo(n_qo) {
  }
  void bar(ExceptionSink *xsink) {
    // convert args if any
    // call virtual function of Foo class, i.e. qo 
    qo->evalMethod("bar", 0, xsink);
  }
```

*QC_Foo.qpp*

```
# implement assign instance function
nothing assignFoo(*Foo foo) {
  QoreAssignFoo(foo->p);
}

#implement class for Qore script
qclass Foo [arg=QoreFooHelper* p]

Foo::constructor() {
  assert(self->validInstanceOf(CID_FOO));   // is it correct test to test if inherited from ?
  QoreFoo* f = new QoreFooHelper(self);
  self->setPrivate(CID_FOO, f);
}

# probably useless as it generates function code
#nothing Foo::bar() {
#}
```

*Test.q*

```
class Foo2 inherits Foo {
  nothing bar() {
    # my stuff
    printf("Hello world from Q");  
  }
}

Foo2 foo();
assignFoo(foo);  # assign instance of Foo2
# wait for "Hello World from Q" message when core calls current_foo.bar()
....
```

Is this feasible solution or even does exist a better way, e.g. using qpp features or avoiding *QoreFooHelper* (but I need avoid overhead when fully implemented *QoreFoo2* in C++) ?

If not then what is alternative option, e.g. passing callref or closure somehow and do real callback ?

**Edit:**

When defining Qore class in .qpp then *qpp* generates class definition *QoreClass* initFoo()* (add methods, constructors,etc.) and registers it into a namespace repository.

When new *QoreObject* is to be created then is constructed with *QoreClass* as parameter found in namespace repo.

.qpp defined constructor normally creates pure C++ *QoreFoo* instance and assigns as private property (*self->setPrivate(CID_FOO, new QoreFoo())*), i.e. link from *Foo* to *QoreFoo* is established and will be used when defining .qpp methods, where is operating with pure C++ stuff. .qpp generated appropriate C++ code into function "header". *self* is *QoreObject* instance.

I think the same is done in runtime for *Foo3* script class.

Qpp helps implementing Qore stuff to call C++ stuff.

But I need opposite direction, calling Qore methods from C++, so I think I need call *QoreObject::evalMethod()*. As QoreObject does not
exist in normal C++ class so extra descendant *QoreFooHelper* is needed to implement it (with extra problem when passing general objects as parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the API you want to enforce is a Qore-language class API, then you need to implement your abstract class in Qore and not in C++.

If you have a C++ virtual class hierarchy that should be extended in Qore, then you should use qpp to implement your Qore class in C++ and then allow programmers to extend it naturally by subclassing your classes in Qore.

You can do it like this:

*QoreFoo.h*

```
class QoreFoo {
public:
     DLLLOCAL QoreFoo(QoreObject* o) : obj(o) {
     }
     // other functions...
private:
     QoreObject* obj;  //!< The QoreObject this private data is associated with
};
```

*QC_Foo.qpp*

```
//! This class defines an abstract interface for ...
/**
 */
qclass Foo [arg=QoreFoo* foo; ns=Foo];

//! Constructor
/** Used by subclasses defined in Qore
 */
Foo::constructor() {
    self->setPrivate(CID_FOO, new QoreFoo(self));
}

//! a method to ...
/**
 */
abstract nothing Foo::bar();
```

This allows class `Foo` to have some private data and an abstract Qore API that can be used by subclasses; subclasses in C++ (implemented with qpp) should declare `Foo` as a `vparent` as in the following example:

*QoreFoo2.h*

```
#include "qore/intern/QoreFoo.h"

class QoreFoo2 : public QoreFoo {
public:
     DLLLOCAL QoreFoo2(QoreObject* o) : QoreFoo(o) {
     }

     DLLLOCAL void bar(ExceptionSink* xsink) {
         printf("Hello World from C++");
     }

     // other functions...
};
```

*QC_Foo2.qpp*

```
#include "qore/intern/QoreFoo2.h"

//! This class ...
/**
 */
qclass Foo2 [arg=QoreFoo2* foo; ns=Foo; vparent=Foo];

//! Constructor
/** Used by subclasses defined in the Qore programming language.
 */
Foo2::constructor() {
    self->setPrivate(CID_FOO2, new QoreFoo2(self));
}

//! a method to ...
/**
 */
nothing Foo2::bar() {
    foo->bar();
}
```

Also the `Foo` class can be directly subclassed in Qore in the same way:

```
class Foo3 inherits Foo {
    bar() {
        print("Hello world from Q");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

@TMa if you want to call a Qore-language method from C++, then use [QoreObject::evalMethodValue()](https://docs.qore.org/current/library/html/class_qore_object.html#aa9de8bea67164c30589751eabcaaddd7) as already mentioned - you are right that qpp does not generate this code for you.

If you want to make sure that the method is implemented in any Qore-language class that inherits the parent class, then make sure to define an abstract Qore method in your qpp file that defines the parent class.

Comment: *current_foo* is actual instance of object *QoreFoo* implementing requested features. Yes thread-safety must be achieved but it is just example.

*qo->evalMethod("bar", 0, xsink);*

Comment: Is my idea of calling *Foo::bar* virtual method from C++ correct ? I though about QoreFooHelper to do it. This class will be used as parent of all qore script *FooXXX* classes.

*qo->evalMethod("bar", 0, xsink);*

When fetaure is fully implemented in C++ as binary module using normal C++ stuff (char, class, pointer, etc.) then it will descend directly *QoreFoo*.

Comment: @TMa it seems like there is some fundamental misunderstanding - `self` is the current Qore object which is passed as an argument to each non-static Qore method in the C++ function that implements that method (i.e. the one generated by qpp) - the C++ object implementing the logic you want needs to be attached to the `QoreObject` (`self`) as private data in the constructor.   Then you call the C++ function that implements the method object on the private data object (which is also passed as an argument to the C++ function).

Comment: Then if the class if overridden in Qore with a user-defined `bar()` method, the Qore runtime will call the user method itself - you don't need to call it manually in C++ code.  In cases where you do need to call a Qore-language method explicitly, then you should use [QoreObject::evalMethodValue()](https://docs.qore.org/current/library/html/class_qore_object.html#aa9de8bea67164c30589751eabcaaddd7) instead.  I suppose my examples were not clear - if not then please allow me to clarify.

Comment: I believe I got it this way. Because of comment limits a edited original post. I need solve C++ to Qore calls and I don't think *qpp* generates a related code, so it's needed to write them manually with extra care when converting C++ (objects!!!) to QoreNode params.

Comment: ok I edited the answer - I hope this helps and answers your question